# MySQL Cluster Installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am very new to mysql-cluster.I downloaded the binaries and was trying to configure it on my local machine.

Can anybody suggest how to install it on single machine with the 1 management node,2 data nodes,1 sql node.

Also what are the importance of each type of node?

I need the basics steps to install the mysql-cluster.As I have installed it by seeing some website and stuck in between i am getting an error as

```
mysql> show warnings;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                         |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Error | 1296 | Got error 4009 'Cluster Failure' from NDB. Could not acquire global schema lock |
| Error | 1296 | Got error 4009 'Cluster Failure' from NDB                                       |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also have gone through the manual but no results.

Anybody can help me out in this?

Comment: can you provide your config files?

Answer (score 3):

For single machine setups, you can also check out the Cluster Sandbox:

http://www.severalnines.com/resources/mysql-cluster-sandbox-pre-defined-packages

Good luck!

Vinay

http://www.severalnines.com/

## Edit By RolandoMySQLDBA 2012-05-15 13:34 EDT

Check out the Training Slides : http://severalnines.com/mysql-cluster-training

IMHO it would be a fine starting point for beginners to install & learn MySQL Cluster.

Answer (score 1):

The Getting Started guides talk you through deployment on a single host - select the guide for your OS and go from there:
http://mysql.com/products/cluster/start.html#getting_started

The Data nodes store all the actual tables of your database. They automatically shard your tables across the nodes, and provide replication, failover, recovery, etc for high availability

The SQL node provides a SQL API to your data

The Management nodes are used at cluster startup and configuration, as well as perform arbitration between nodes

You can learn more about the architecture of MySQL Cluster from this whitepaper (registration required):
http://mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_scaling_web_databases.php

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following the below tutorials:

http://www.null-byte.org/development/mysql-ndb-cluster-setup-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

http://bromokun.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/installing-mysql-cluster-management-node-in-ubuntu-server-v-12-04/